# Unity 3D 2018 WebGL Build in Monterey failing -- Cannot find python

Tags: python, macos, unity-game-engine, webgl

After upgrading to Monterey on my Mac I can no longer build a webGL build out of a legacy Unity project. I can't update without a major overhaul of my project. During the build process I keep getting the following error:

```
stdout:
stderr:2022-05-23 11:12:04.488 xcodebuild[2036:176160] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore2022-05-23 11:12:04.488 xcodebuild[2036:176160] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCorepython: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find python 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 17664: (null) (errno=Invalid argument)xcode-select: Failed to locate 'python', requesting installation of command line developer tools.
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

If I run the `xcodebuild -sdk` search manually in Terminal, it produces a path to python 2.7. I can also run python 2.7 from the terminal using the python alias.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Try `xcode-select --install` in a terminal to be sure the command line tools are installed correctly.

Comment: After running that command it appears I'm up-to-date with command line tools. I found I needed some updates but still no difference in building out of unity. It still wants command line tools installed.